# Visualize data in Power BI from Azure Databricks Delta Lake

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-databricks, powerbi-embedded, delta-lake

I have a requirement like this:

1. Source data will come from Azure SQL (master data) and Azure Cosmos Db (transactional data)
2. Create a data model in Azure Databricks using Delta Lake
3. Create visualizations in Power BI Embedded

I am very new to Delta Lake. So, pardon my noob questions.

My questions are:

1. How should we create the data model (DWH)
2. Should we use Direct Query or Import Data in Power BI to visualize the data